# Custom email sent with template empty in observer after order

Tags: event-observer, template, order-email

I have an observer that sends an email after order is placed to another email adress depending on a custom attribute.
I have the following in config.php

```
  <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
      <observers>
        <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
        <type>singleton</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
        <class>email/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
        <method>ccMyEmail</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
        <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
      </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action_handler>
    </observers>
  </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
```

and in observer.php

```
public function ccMyEmail(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
        {
            $order_ids = $observer->getData('order_ids');

if(isset($order_ids)) {
    foreach ($order_ids as $order_id) :

    $sendToMe = false;


    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);
        if (isset($order)) {

             $orderItems = $order->getAllItems();
             foreach ($orderItems as $_item) {

                 $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getData('product_id'));

                 $attrValue = $product->getResource()->getAttribute(
$product->getId(),
'email_card',
Mage::app()->getStore()
);

$emailadress = $product->getData('email_adress');
       if($attrValue == ('Yes' || '1')) {

                          $sendToMe = true;
                 }

             }
         }

     if($sendToMe) {

$emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
$templateId = 1;
$emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->load($templateId);

    //$emailTemplate->loadDefault('order_new');
    $emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject('Your order was holded');

    // Get General email address (Admin->Configuration->General->Store Email Addresses)
    $salesData['email'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
    $salesData['name'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name');

    $emailTemplate->setSenderName($salesData['name']);
    $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail($salesData['email']);

    $emailTemplateVariables['username']  = $order->getCustomerFirstname() . ' ' . $order->getCustomerLastname();
    $emailTemplateVariables['order_id'] = $order->getIncrementId();
    $emailTemplateVariables['store_name'] = $order->getStoreName();
    $emailTemplateVariables['store_url'] = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);
    $emailTemplate->send('example@gmail.com', $order->getStoreName(), $emailTemplateVariables);
```

The email gets sent but the template doesnt have the data of the order. What is wrong?

UPDATE I realize now that i have to put in all the email template variables in order to retrieve a full template with the data but is there noway to get the all data just by giving the id of the order?

Comment: What is `$templateId = 1;` ?

Comment: it is the id of the template.